# Linq Expression Could Not Be Translated - DistinctBy Breaking Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, iqueryable

Whenever I run this I get the above error. I am on .NET Core 6 and EF Core.

For some reason I only get the error when the DistinctBy clause is in there.

```
var notifications = _context.Notifications.Where(x => x.ToUser == user.Id);
                
if (!getRead)
{
   notifications = notifications
      .Where(x => x.IsRead == false);
}

if (getUnique)
{
   notifications = notifications.DistinctBy(x => x.SuggestionId);
}

return await notifications
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
   .ToListAsync();
```

The goal is to get a list of notifications that only show the latest notification about a certain Suggestion. I have tried the GroupBy ... Select way of going about it but that doesnt work either.